# How to enforce NTP authentication?

Tags: ntp, chrony

I have configured NTP server on an Ubuntu machine and NTP client on a Centos 9 Stream using Chrony. I have enabled authentication on both server and client, but when I put differnt keys on the sides, the sync is still successful! How can I enforce NTP authentication and prevent sync in case of key mismatch?

Here are my settings:

Server:

```
# cat /etc/chrony/chrony.conf
pool ntp.ubuntu.com        iburst maxsources 4
pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst maxsources 1
pool 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst maxsources 1
pool 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst maxsources 2

keyfile /etc/chrony/chrony.keys
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/chrony.drift
logdir /var/log/chrony
maxupdateskew 100.0
rtcsync
makestep 1 3

allow 192.168.1.0/24
```

```
# cat /etc/chrony/chrony.keys
1 MD5 111222
```

Client:

```
#cat /etc/chrony.conf
sourcedir /run/chrony-dhcp
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift
makestep 1.0 3
rtcsync
keyfile /etc/chrony.keys
ntsdumpdir /var/lib/chrony
leapsectz right/UTC
logdir /var/log/chrony
server 192.168.1.10
```

```
# cat /etc/chrony.keys
1 MD5 55555555
```

```
# chronyc ntpdata

Remote address  : 192.168.1.10 (290C1402)
Remote port     : 123
Local address   : 192.168.1.14 (0A0A3833)
Leap status     : Normal
Version         : 4
Mode            : Server
Stratum         : 3
Poll interval   : 10 (1024 seconds)
Precision       : -25 (0.000000030 seconds)
Root delay      : 0.008575 seconds
Root dispersion : 0.001907 seconds
Reference ID    : 4C7CE64A ()
Reference time  : Thu Aug 04 09:45:39 2022
Offset          : +0.000157768 seconds
Peer delay      : 0.000969113 seconds
Peer dispersion : 0.000000050 seconds
Response time   : 0.000046875 seconds
Jitter asymmetry: +0.00
NTP tests       : 111 111 1111
Interleaved     : No
Authenticated   : No
TX timestamping : Daemon
RX timestamping : Kernel
Total TX        : 36
Total RX        : 36
Total valid RX  : 36
```

```
# timedatectl status
               Local time: Thu 2022-08-04 10:12:18 UTC
           Universal time: Thu 2022-08-04 10:12:18 UTC
                 RTC time: Thu 2022-08-04 10:12:17
                Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

Comment: I don't see any way to configure in chrony, if it doesn't do it by default when there is a keyfile. You might need to move to real ntp, in which case the client line `server 192.168.1.10` needs to have the key number added, eg `key 1`. See also the chrony `nts` security option, which seems a bit complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the answer. We can enforce the authentication using the `key [KEY ID]` keyword at the end of server or pool statement as such:

```
server 192.168.1.10 key 1
```

Sheer setting the keyfile does not enforce authentication and without `key` time will sync even if the keyword is not set or there is a key mismatch.